# Global php variable doesn't affect output of function

Tags: javascript, php, variables, global-variables

I am trying to implement this example on my website: http://jsfiddle.net/eDeQr/1/
The problem is that I need the `$cp1 = 4;`variable to be global and not inside that function. As soon as I do that the function doesn't give any output in the second field.

This is what I want it to look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calc() {
    var textValue1 = document.getElementById('input1').value;
    var textValue2 = $cp1;

    document.getElementById('output').value = textValue1 * textValue2;
};
</script>
```

The `$cp1` variable should be global.

Comment: Just define the variable outside of the function: http://jsfiddle.net/eDeQr/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing JavaScript and PHP. You actually have to echo out the PHP variable inside of your JavaScript. Otherwise the JavaScript is looking for a JavaScript variable named `$cpl` which is undefined.

```
var textValue2 = <?php echo $cp1; ?>
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks for the help! I will mark this as soon as I am allowed to.